# Cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using this script to open a dialog. But, it throws an error :

> Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="content-wrapper" style="display:none">
    <div id="dialog-error" title="LIST ERROR">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <span class="text text-green"><b>FIELD</b></span>
                    <div id="container-field">
                        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover" >
                            <tbody id="container-field-error">

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="row">
                        <span class="text text-green"><b>ERROR MESSAGE</b></span>
                        <div id="container-message" style="min-height: 150px">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <span class="text text-green"><b>TYPE</b></span>
                        <div id="container-type" style="min-height: 150px">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the script:

```
$("#dialog-error").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: '700px',
        resizeable: false,
        position: {
            my: 'top',
            at: 'top+150',
            of: window
        }
    });
$('.btn-list-error').live('click', function () {
        $('#dialog-error').dialog('open');
    });
```

And here is the jQuery versions in my code:

```
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl ?>/js/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl ?>/js/jQuery/jQuery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl ?>/js/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl ?>/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl ?>/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>-->
<script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl ?>/js/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl ?>/js/common-scripts.js"></script>
```

Anyone can help me what is the problem here? Is the jQuery conflict?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what is the matter here. In my case, the problem is in html code. There is an error in my html code. I was wrong in using css class. Once i fixed the error, the code runs well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize your jquery dialog before calling the open function. In your html you can do initialization of jquery in head element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         initializeDialog();
    });
</script>
```

And change your js file to have the dialog code in initializeDialog() function.

```
function initializeDialog(){
  $("#dialog-error").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: '700px',
    resizeable: false,
    position: {
        my: 'top',
        at: 'top+150',
        of: window
    }
  });
}
```